# Akka : message processing against thread utilization

Tags: multithreading, akka

When message comes in mailbox, scheduler picks an actor, resume it and put it on OS thread. Java threads maps with OS thread to do execution.

Actor will use one thread from pool and use this thread for messages processing and release the thread to pool.

Actor doesn't have dedicated thread. There is a pool of threads and an actor will use allotted thread for processing message and once message processing done, thread will be released. So, Actor is decoupled from thread.

Now lets take an example :

```
public class GreetingActor extends UntypedActor {
    LoggingAdapter log = Logging.getLogger(getContext().system(), this);

    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        if (message instanceof String) {
            String sRmsg = (String) message;
            businessImpl.collectdata(sRmsg); // assume this method takes 1 mins for completion
        }
    }
}


ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("MySystem");
ActorRef greeter = system.actorOf(new Props(GreetingActor.class), "greeter");
greeter.tell("Charlie Parker");
```

Here, greeter actor sends message using tell method, So this message will go in mailbox queue and scheduler will pick the message from queue and invoke actor with the message.

When the message is received in GreetingActor's 'onReceive' method - My question is when will the actor-utilized Thread be released back to the pool-
Either after receiving message in  onReceive method OR after execution of collectdata() method ?

Also, What does 'Message Processing' indicate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
businessImpl.collectdata(sRmsg); // assume this method takes 1 mins for completion
```

If this line can potentially take that much time, then it should be
considered as a blocking call. There is a section in the documentation
that explains how such situations can be handled safely:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/general/actor-systems.html#blocking-needs-careful-management

> When the message is received in GreetingActor's 'onReceive' method - My
>   question is when will the actor-utilized Thread be released back to the
>   pool-
>   Either after receiving message in  onReceive method OR after execution of
>   collectdata() method ?

It will "release" the thread back to the pool after the execution of
the long collectdata() call -- therefore the above code is dangerous.

The link I pasted above has some nice patterns how to work around
this, IF you can not split up the task into smaller pieces (for
example because you use an external library you have no control over).

If you can split up that method into finer granularity short-time
tasks handled by actors and message passing, then you don't need the
special handling.

-Endre, 
Akka Team

Comment: Thanks for adding my answer from the mailing list, I wasn't aware that it was posted as a StackOverflow question as well.